# Subtracting two SELECTs in another SELECT in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to subtract the results from two different `select` calls in SQLAlchemy as another `select` to finally call in an `order_by` to recreate the following query:

```sql
SELECT reviews.id FROM reviews
ORDER BY (
    SELECT (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM review_upvoters WHERE review_id = reviews.id
    ) - (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM review_downvoters WHERE review_id = reviews.id
    )
);
```

I've tried simply subtracting the two selects from each other (`query_one - query_two`), two no avail, and skimming the SQLAlchemy docs but they haven't exactly helped.

What I've currently got is this:

```py
upvoters_count = select([func.count()]).where(ReviewUpvoters.review_id == Review.id)
downvoters_count = select([func.count()]).where(ReviewDownvoters.review_id == Review.id)
reviews = Reviews.query.order_by(...)
```

where I'm trying to figure out the inside of the `order_by` to properly subtract these `select`s.

(If `Reviews.query` looks weird, it's because I'm using Gino for asynchronous Postgres support, but it uses regular SQLAlchemy objects for the most part so this shouldn't affect anything.)

Since `__sub__` doesn't appear to be defined on `Select` objects, I'm a bit stumped on doing this, and I'm not 100% keen on restructuring the tables so these two are in the same table with something to differentiate them.

Comment: not sure of this: try `Reviews.query.order_by(upvoters_count.as_scalar() - downvoters_count.as_scalar())` https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.SelectBase.as_scalar

Comment: @Tryph sweet that seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Tryph, I got it working using `as_scalar()` on the subqueries.

```py
upvoters_count = select([func.count()]).where(ReviewUpvoters.review_id == Review.id).as_scalar()
downvoters_count = select([func.count()]).where(ReviewDownvoters.review_id == Review.id).as_scalar()
query = Reviews.query.order_by(upvoters_count - downvoters_count)
```

which produces the following query which is comparable to my original one

```sql
SELECT reviews.id, reviews.created_at, reviews.rating, reviews.content, reviews.title, reviews.mod_id, reviews.author_id
FROM reviews
ORDER BY (
    SELECT count(*) AS count_1
    FROM review_upvoters
    WHERE review_upvoters.review_id = reviews.id
) - (
    SELECT count(*) AS count_2
    FROM review_downvoters
    WHERE review_downvoters.review_id = reviews.id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not refactor this query a bit? I think it'd be faster, and it'd definitely simplify what you have to ask sqlalchemy to do.

```
SELECT reviews.id
FROM reviews
LEFT JOIN review_upvoters ON reviews.id = review_upvoters.review_id
LEFT JOIN review_downvoters ON reviews.id = review_downvoters.review_id
GROUP BY reviews.id
ORDER BY
COUNT(DISTINCT review_upvoters.id) - COUNT(DISTINCT review_downvoters.id)
;
```

Comment: From my testing this doesn't seem to be giving the same result my original query

https://gist.github.com/Ovyerus/dfe1a49966fed5b982d3d7417f63939e

Comment: I believe you'll need COUNT (DISTINCT) since there are two joins going on